# PosTag library to tag sentences with mistakes

Tags: python, library, machine-learning, nlp

I am developing an Intelligent tutor system. I have sentences with mistakes in determiners. I need a library in python that postag the sentences with these mistakes so that I can diagnose the error and teach learners of my system.

Comment: POStag == https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging